# Calculate the euclidean distance in scipy csr matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, euclidean-distance

I need to calculate the Euclidean Distance between all points that is stored in csr sparse matrix and some lists of points. It would be easier for me to convert the csr to a dense one, but I couldn't due to the lack of memory, so I need to keep it as csr.

So for example I have this **data_csr** sparse matrix (view in both, csr and dense):

```
data_csr
(0, 2)  4
(1, 0)  1
(1, 4)  2
(2, 0)  2
(2, 3)  1
(3, 5)  1
(4, 0)  4
(4, 2)  3
(4, 3)  2

data_csr.todense()
[[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
 [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 [4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0]]
```

and this **center** lists of points:

```
center
array([[0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1],
      [3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 0]])
```

using the `scipy.spatial` package, the Euclidean Distance array between **data_csr** and **center**  will be like the one below. So each point, of total 6 points, in each row of **center** was calculated against all rows in **data_csr**. The first row of the result array(2,5) is the ED between the first row of **center** and all rows in **data_csr**.

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(center, data_csr, 'euclidean')

array([[ 5.09901951,  3.87298335,  5.19615242,  5.        ,  5.91607978],
      [ 7.34846923,  5.38516481,  5.91607978,  6.8556546 ,  6.08276253]])
```

What I've learned so far that I can get the nonzero values as well the indices with:

```
data_csr.data
array([4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2])

data_csr.indices
array([2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 3])
```

But still I can't figure out how to calculate the ED between these two objects.

Comment: How do you calculate the ED between data_csr and center (assuming dense)?

Comment: @Alexander I've edited it, I use the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(center, data_csr, 'euclidean')`

Comment: I still cannot replicate your results to calculate the distances above.  See this post for how to extract the data from the matrix, which is as far as I've got. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587702/convert-sparse-matrix-csc-matrix-to-pandas-dataframe/36587845#36587845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's create your matrix (too bad you didn't give inputs that I could copy-n-paste)

```
In [114]: data=[4,1,2,2,1,1,4,3,2]   
In [115]: col=[0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]
In [116]: row=[2,0,4,0,3,5,0,2,3]
In [117]: M=sparse.csr_matrix((data,(col,row)))

In [118]: M
Out[118]: 
<5x6 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [119]: M.A
Out[119]: 
array([[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0]])

In [121]: center=np.array([[0,1,2,2,4,1],[3,4,1,2,4,0]])
```

So how did you calculate the distance?  `M.A` is (5,6), `center` is (2,6).  It's not obvious what you are doing with these two arrays.

As for access to the 'raw' sparse values, the `coo` format is easiest to understand.  It's the same row,col,data stuff I used to create the matrix

```
In [131]: M.tocoo().data
Out[131]: array([4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2])

In [132]: M.tocoo().col
Out[132]: array([2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 3])

In [133]: M.tocoo().row
Out[133]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

The `csr` stores the same info in `data`, `indices` and `indptr` arrays. But you have to do some math to pull to the `i,j` values from the last 2.  `csr` multiplication routines make good use of these arrays.

In general it is better to do multiplication with `csr` matrices than addition/subtraction.

I await further clarification.

---

```
spatial.distance.cdist(center,M.A, 'euclidean')
Out[156]: 
array([[ 5.09901951,  3.87298335,  5.19615242,  5.        ,  5.91607978],
       [ 7.34846923,  5.38516481,  5.91607978,  6.8556546 ,  6.08276253]])
```

What we need to do is study this function, and understand its inputs.  We may have to go beyond its docs and look at the code.

But looking at this code I see steps to ensure that `xB` is 2d array, with the same number of columns as `xA`.  Then for `euclidian` it calls

```
_distance_wrap.cdist_euclidean_wrap(_convert_to_double(XA),
                                    _convert_to_double(XB), dm)
```

which looks like a wrapper on some C code.  I can't imagine any way of feeding it a sparse matrix.

You could iterate over rows; calling `dist` with `M[[0],:].A` is the same as `M.A[[0],:]` - except for speed.  Iterating over rows of a sparse matrix is kind of slow, as much because it has to construct a new sparse matrix at each iteration.  `csr` and `lil` are the 2 fastest for row iteration.

Here's something that might be faster - directly iterating on the attributes of the `lil` format:

```
 def foo(a,b,n):
    # make a dense array from data,row
    res = np.zeros((1,n))
    res[0,b]=a
    return res

In [190]: Ml=M.tolil()

In [191]: Ml.data
Out[191]: array([[4], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1], [4, 3, 2]], dtype=object)

In [192]: Ml.rows
Out[192]: array([[2], [0, 4], [0, 3], [5], [0, 2, 3]], dtype=object)

In [193]: rowgen=(foo(a,b,6) for a,b in zip(Ml.data,Ml.rows))

In [194]: np.concatenate([spatial.distance.cdist(center,row, 'euclidean') for row in rowgen],axis=1)
Out[194]: 
array([[ 5.09901951,  3.87298335,  5.19615242,  5.        ,  5.91607978],
       [ 7.34846923,  5.38516481,  5.91607978,  6.8556546 ,  6.08276253]])
```

For now I'll skip the time tests.

Comment: I've edited the case and explain how did I calculate it, hope it's clear enough to understand. Using the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(center, data_csr, 'euclidean')`

Answer (score 4):

Pairwise euclidian distance on sparse matrices is implemented in sklearn (as pointed out by hpaulj, the scipy implementation does not work on sparse matrices).

Example on hpaulj example:

```
import scipy.sparse
import sklearn.metrics.pairwise
data = [4,1,2,2,1,1,4,3,2]  
col = [0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]
row = [2,0,4,0,3,5,0,2,3]
M = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data,(col,row)))
distances = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(M,M)
```

Documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html

Comment: just to understand, on the sparse matrix context. I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794849/efficient-and-precise-calculation-of-the-euclidean-distance) and seems like the `sklearn``pairwise_distances` is very "inefficient" but on the other hand here seems like a good alternative, which one do you think is the fastest ?