# Convert sparse matrix (csc_matrix) to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-analysis, word-frequency

I want to convert this matrix into a pandas dataframe.
[csc_matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYkPp.png)

The **first** number in the bracket should be the **index**, the **second** number being **columns** and the **number in the end** being the **data**.

I want to do this to do feature selection in text analysis, the first number represents the document, the second being the feature of word and the last number being the TFIDF score.

Getting a dataframe helps me to transform the text analysis problem into data analysis.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

csc = csc_matrix(np.array(
    [[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
     [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0]]))

# Return a Coordinate (coo) representation of the Compresses-Sparse-Column (csc) matrix.
coo = csc.tocoo(copy=False)

# Access `row`, `col` and `data` properties of coo matrix.
>>> pd.DataFrame({'index': coo.row, 'col': coo.col, 'data': coo.data}
                 )[['index', 'col', 'data']].sort_values(['index', 'col']
                 ).reset_index(drop=True)
   index  col  data
0      0    2     4
1      1    0     1
2      1    4     2
3      2    0     2
4      2    3     1
5      3    5     1
6      4    0     4
7      4    2     3
8      4    3     2
```