# How to create an increasing, multi-dimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I am trying to perform inverse warping given a homography matrix, and to do that efficiently I need a numpy array that looks like this:

```
([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], ... [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], ... [n, p, 1]])
```

Where n is an image's width (`im.shape[0]`) and p is the image's height (`im.shape[1]`). Any idea on how to efficiently construct numpy arrays that look like that?

**Edit:**

There is some discussion on which is the fastest, if anyone has any info on that I think it'd be interesting to hear. I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: You don't need to state "appreciation of help" - you [generally just upvote every answer that was helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But stating that you're interested in benchmarks or the fastest solution is appropriate. But maybe you want to [edit] your "edit". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`indices_merged_arr_generic_using_cp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135435/3293881) by @unutbu -

```
def indices_one_grid(n,p):
    ar = np.ones((n,p),dtype=int)
    return indices_merged_arr_generic_using_cp(ar)
```

Sample run -

```
In [141]: indices_one_grid(n=3,p=4)
Out[141]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 1]])
```

### Benchmarking

Other approaches -

```
def MSeifert(n,p):
    x, y = np.mgrid[:n, :p]
    return np.stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), np.ones(x.size, dtype=int)], axis=1)

def DanielF(n,p):
    return np.vstack([np.indices((n,p)), np.ones((1, n,p))]).reshape(3,-1).T

def Aaron(n,p):
    arr = np.empty([n*p,3])
    arr[:,0] = np.repeat(np.arange(n),p)
    arr[:,1] = np.tile(np.arange(p),n)
    arr[:,2] = 1
    return arr
```

Timings -

```
In [152]: n=1000;p=1000

In [153]: %timeit MSeifert(n,p)
     ...: %timeit DanielF(n,p)
     ...: %timeit Aaron(n,p)
     ...: %timeit indices_one_grid(n,p)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.46 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.78 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome benchmarking. Thank you for such an in depth response!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) to create the grid (first two entries of each subarray) with [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) to concatenate them:

```
>>> x, y = np.mgrid[:3, :3]   # assuming a 3x3 image
>>> np.stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), np.ones(x.size, dtype=int)], axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 1]])
```

In this case I used 3 as width and height but by altering the arguments for `np.mgrid` you can change them.

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
np.vstack([np.indices(im.shape), np.ones((1, *im.shape))]).reshape(3,-1).T
```

Basically, key to getting indices like this is using something like `indices`, `mgrid`/`meshgrid` or the like.

Comment: I think you've got a typo there.  *

Comment: @johnktejik Nope, that's to unpack the tuple

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all without looping using `numpy.tile` and `numpy.repeat` and a pre-allocated container

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.empty([n*p,3])
arr[:,0] = np.repeat(np.arange(n),p)
arr[:,1] = np.tile(np.arange(p),n)
arr[:,2] = 1
```

Comment: I always forget that 2D that's the easier and faster method.

Comment: @MSeifert what can sometimes be slow is the memory allocation incurred by np.stack... probably true with indices being faster than repeat and tile though.

Comment: @Aaron It's the same memory allocation just different order. I create the small arrays first and then use stack to create the big one. While you create the big one first and then create small ones that are copied into the large array.