# Create specific array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to create this kind of array using numpy:

```
[[[0,0,0], [1,0,0], ..., [1919,0,0]],
 [[0,1,0], [1,1,0], ..., [1919,1,0]],
 ...,
 [[0,1019,0], [1,1019,0], ..., [1919,1019,0]]]
```

To which I can access via:

```
>>> data[25][37]
array([25, 37, 0])
```

I've tried to create an array this way, but it's not complete:

```
>>> data = np.mgrid[0:1920:1, 0:1080:1].swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(0,1)
>>> data[25][37]
array([25, 37])
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this using numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one way with `np.ogrid` and `array-initialization` -

```
def indices_zero_grid(m,n):
    I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
    out = np.zeros((m,n,3), dtype=int)
    out[...,0] = I
    out[...,1] = J
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [550]: out = indices_zero_grid(1920,1080)

In [551]: out[25,37]
Out[551]: array([25, 37,  0])
```

**Approach #2 :** A modification of [`@senderle's cartesian_product`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/) and also inspired by [@unutbu's modification to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135435/) -

```
import functools
def indices_zero_grid_v2(m,n):
    """
    Based on cartesian_product
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645 (@senderle)
    Inspired by : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135435 (@unutbu)
    """
    shape = m,n
    arrays = [np.arange(s, dtype='int') for s in shape]
    broadcastable = np.ix_(*arrays)
    broadcasted = np.broadcast_arrays(*broadcastable)
    rows, cols = functools.reduce(np.multiply, broadcasted[0].shape), \
                                                  len(broadcasted)+1
    out = np.zeros(rows * cols, dtype=int)
    start, end = 0, rows
    for a in broadcasted:
        out[start:end] = a.reshape(-1)
        start, end = end, end + rows
    return out.reshape(-1,m,n).transpose(1,2,0)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [2]: %timeit indices_zero_grid(1920,1080)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.4 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit indices_zero_grid_v2(1920,1080)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.14 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm seeing a 25% improvement in speed for approach #2 if `out = np.empty(...)` is changed to `out = np.zeros(...)` and thus allowing `out[start:] = 0` to be omitted.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks. Yes, I figure that after optimizing app#1 likewise, but didn't push it through.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [50]: data = np.mgrid[:1920, :1080, :1].transpose(1,2,3,0)[..., 0, :]

In [51]: data[25][37]
Out[51]: array([25, 37,  0])
```

Note that `data[25][37]` two calls to `__getitem__`. With NumPy arrays, you can access the same value more efficiently (with one call to `__getitem__`) using `data[25, 37]`:

```
In [54]: data[25, 37]
Out[54]: array([25, 37,  0])
```

Comment: Maybe add : `[...,0,:]` at the end/squeeze to remove the singleton dim.

Comment: I've tried both solutions but @Divakar is about 2 times faster. Thanks You!

Comment: Added your older solution trick for some speedup in my post. Hope that's okay :)

Comment: @Divakar: Absolutely! It's great to see senderle's invention finding applications.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Edited app#1 with zeros initialization and that's considerably faster now. @wnukers Check out the updated version of app#1 for a faster one.

Comment: @Divakar thanks for your updated version, it is quite faster than older.
Now I wanted to make 2d histogram from this data, which (x,y) is coordinates and third element is number of occurrences (data[25,37] and (x,y) = (25,37)). Do you think I should create new topic for this problem, or maybe you know how to do this easy way?

Comment: @wnukers Yes, post a new question please.