# Is there a way to put attributes linked to array coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

Creating a 10x10x10 coordinate grid

```
#10x10x10
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)
z = np.arange(0,10)

coordinates= []

#makes coordinates for the 10x10x10
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            coordinates.append((x[i], y[j], z[k]))
```

So this is my code that has an coordinates from (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)... to (9,9,9).

I want to be able to treat each coordinate as an object that has information. Example would be (0,0,0) has 1 apples, 2 oranges, 3 lemons. (0,0,1) has 1 apples, 0 oranges 0 lemons, so on so forth. Is there a way to store information linked to each coordinate?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135070/ Also `np.indices`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary with the coordinates, and make each entry a dictionary with the information you want:

```
#10x10x10
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)
z = np.arange(0,10)

coordinates = {}
#makes coordinates for the 10x10x10
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            obj_in_coord = {
                'apples': 4,
                'oranges': 2,
                'lemons': 6
            }
            coordinates[(x[i], y[j], z[k])] = obj_in_coord
print coordinates[(2,3,7)]['apples']  # outputs 4
```

If you leave it like this, of course, every coordinate will have 4 apples, 2 oranges and 6 lemons. You should apply your logic when creating `obj_in_coord`.

To access to the information with integers, simply change obj_in_coord to a list:

```
#10x10x10
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)
z = np.arange(0,10)

coordinates = {}
#makes coordinates for the 10x10x10
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            info_in_coord = [4, 2, 6]
            coordinates[(x[i], y[j], z[k])] = info_in_coord
print coordinates[(2,3,7)][0]  # outputs 4
```

Comment: That's very close to what I want. However, is there a way to replace the strings such as 'apples' to integer variables?

Comment: Say you want to know the number of applpes in the square (2,3,7). How do you want to access it. With `coordinates[(2,3,7)]['apples']` (you access the property apple) or `coordinates[(2,3,7)][0]` (you access the first propery)

Answer (score 1):

you could maintain a dict to have fruits and key is coordinates

```
fruits = {(0,0,0):{'apples':1, 'oranges':2, 'lemons':3},
          }
```

or

```
fruits = {(0,0,0):[1, 2, 3],
          }
```

Comment: The second part of your answer with fransico's was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!