# numpy create array of all coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a list of all possible (x,y) values.

For example - for input (x=2,y=3) the output should be:

```
np.array([
[0,0],
[0,1],
[0,2],
[1,0],
[1,1],
[1,2]])
```

The order doesn't really matter

Comment: Please update our question with your previous attempts.

Comment: Have you looked at [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) ?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? If you store this code in an array, it will give you this output...

Comment: Reopening as it isn't a duplicate of those links, regardless of whatever else it might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
>>> np.argwhere(np.ones((2, 3)))
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: I don't care about the upvotes, but I finally 1UP'd you on an answer ;)

Comment: And coversely I am relishing the success of my populist answer ;-)

Comment: Meh. By the way, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Certainly not the best links with that.

Comment: This question is pretty much a duplicate but I couldn't find exactly the same duplicate. However, the answer of this question can be found within target questions's answers. Please add the questions to the list if you found a more accurate one. Also a much faster approach for this solution (specially fir larger arrays) could be `np.dstack(np.indices((2, 3))).reshape(6, 2)`.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Divakar's [`indices_merged_arr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45857632/4909087), this should be *fast*.

```
def indices_for(m, n):
    i, j = np.ogrid[:m, :n]
    v = np.empty((m, n, 2), dtype=np.uint32)
    v[..., 0] = i
    v[..., 1] = j
    v.shape = (-1, 2)

    return v
```

```
>>> indices_for(3, 2)
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

---

```
m, n = 10000, 10000
%timeit indices_for(m, n)
607 ms ± 9.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.argwhere(np.ones((m, n)))
4.69 s ± 225 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Now that you reopened a quation with no attempt please add a benchmark with `np.dstack(np.indices((m, n))).reshape(m*n, 2)` too :)). Nice attempt tho(+).

Comment: @Kasramvd not on my machine now so can't benchmark :( but I've tried something similar with hstack and np.indices (I am aware of the function) but it's performance severely left something to be desired. Anyway, I'll test it in the morning. I'm still not convinced of the closure but it definitely could be a dupe of something else... so let me know and I'll close it when I get my votes back (I'm all out for today).

Comment: @Kasramvd wait, can you please try it for m,n=10000,10000 as in my answer?

Comment: I was about to do that it the IPython raises memory error. This is problem with Ipyhton-3 that I always encounter to.

Comment: @Kasramvd what is your code doing that ours isn't? :P

Comment: @I tried other snippets and my machine with 16 GB RAM went to halt!! :))