# scipy cdist with sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to calculate the distances between two sets of vectors, `source_matrix` and `target_matrix`.

I have the following line, when both `source_matrix` and `target_matrix` are of type `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`:

```
distances = sp.spatial.distance.cdist(source_matrix, target_matrix)
```

And I end up getting the following partial exception traceback:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 2060, in cdist
    [XA] = _copy_arrays_if_base_present([_convert_to_double(XA)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 146, in _convert_to_double
    X = X.astype(np.double)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Which seem to indicate the sparse matrices are being treated as dense numpy matrices, which both fails and misses the point of using sparse matrices.

Any advice?

Comment: `cdist` expects its arguments to be numpy arrays.  It does not handle scipy's sparse matrices.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Is there a sparse-friendly alternative to `cdist` then?

Comment: @NirIzr Could you please include a portion of your `source` and `target` matrix?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557472/calculate-the-euclidean-distance-in-scipy-csr-matrix - it talks about sparse, and distance.cdist.

Comment: @NirIzr: See [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I appreciate this post is quite old, but as one of the comments suggested, you could use the [sklearn implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) which accepts sparse vectors and matrices.

Take two random vectors for example

```
a = scipy.sparse.rand(m=1,n=100,density=0.2,format='csr')
b = scipy.sparse.rand(m=1,n=100,density=0.2,format='csr')
sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(X=a, Y=b, metric='euclidean')
>>> array([[ 3.14837228]]) # example output
```

Or even if `a` is a matrix and `b` is a vector:

```
a = scipy.sparse.rand(m=500,n=100,density=0.2,format='csr')
b = scipy.sparse.rand(m=1,n=100,density=0.2,format='csr')
sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(X=a, Y=b, metric='euclidean')
>>> array([[ 2.9864606 ], # example output
   [ 3.33862248],
   [ 3.45803465],
   [ 3.15453179],
   ...
```

Scipy spatial.distance does not support sparse matrices, so sklearn would be the best choice here. You can also pass the `n_jobs` argument to `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances` which distributes the computation if your vectors are very large.

Hope that helps

Comment: I recall using pairwise_distances didn't turn out too well for me, but can't really say why. Therefore, I'm accepting but not upvoting this answer in hopes it'll be upvoted by users finding it helpful.

Comment: Checked using `timeit`, `cdist`  is over twice as fast as `pairwise_distances`.